How to create vnodes from a string with html tags in vue 3
Research
So I've found this answer on how to create a vnode list from a simple SVG with one path layer and how to transform that in Vue2.
I could not find any good solutions for Vue 3, so I scaffolded something together based on my knowledge of Vue and some docs on MDN
What I want
A way to transform a HTML string that contains a tree of nodes to Vue Nodes.

What I came up with
I tried to recursively find all nodes in the string and them push them to an array of vNodes that gets bound in the end to one root node.
const parsedTree = (props, context) => {
  let {content} = props

  const div = document.createElement('div')
  div.innerHTML = content
const getAttrs = (node) => {const attrs = {}; for (const attr of node.attributes) attrs[attr.name] = attr.value; return attrs;}
  const htmlToNodes = (nodes) => {
    return Array.from(nodes).map(element => {
      // 3 is #text, not sure how else to build this one
      if (element.nodeType === 3) return h('span', element.nodeValue)

      if (element.childNodes.length)
        return h(element.tagName, getAttrs(element), htmlToNodes(element.childNodes))

      return h(element.tagName, getAttrs(element), element.innerHTML)
    })
  }
  const hElements = htmlToNodes(div.childNodes)

  return h(`div`, {...context.attrs}, hElements)
}

The whole function is inside a functional component that you can add in a template:
// parsedTree.ts
import { h } from 'vue'

const parsedTree = (props, context) => {
  let {content} = props

  const div = document.createElement('div')
  div.innerHTML = content
const getAttrs = (node) => {const attrs = {}; for (const attr of node.attributes) attrs[attr.name] = attr.value; return attrs;}
  const htmlToNodes = (nodes) => {
    return Array.from(nodes).map(element => {
      // 3 is #text, not sure how else to build this one
      if (element.nodeType === 3) return h('span', element.nodeValue)

      if (element.childNodes.length)
        return h(element.tagName, getAttrs(element), htmlToNodes(element.childNodes))

      return h(element.tagName, getAttrs(element), element.innerHTML)
    })
  }
  const hElements = htmlToNodes(div.childNodes)

  return h(`div`, {...context.attrs}, hElements)
}

parsedTree.props = ['content']

export default parsedTree

<template>
<parsed-tree :content="myHTML"/>
</template>
<script setup>
const myHTML = "<div><p>Hello <button>Click!</button> some more text</p><p><em>cursive <strong>and bold</strong> stuff</em></p></div>"
</script>

Key is, that in the parsedTree render, you can check nodes and transform them if needed. In my case, I wanted to transform a plain button that gets set in Tiptap to a custom VBtn from Vuetify
When putting (in my case) the following code below the #text node check, I can add a Vuetify button based on my input
...
      if (element.attributes.getNamedItem('data-id')?.value === 'richTextBtn')
        return h(VBtn, {onClick($event) { alert('hello!')}}, [element.innerHTML])
...

Future
I hope this helps someone else in the struggle I had, please feel free to comment or add your own solution, very happy to see them!
